# Get value on close fancybox not working MVC C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fancybox

I have a partialview that opens a fancybox with the same model of the main view, so far so ok, the problem is to rescue a value that is in a hidden field on the form that are in this partialview fancybox. I can not even show alerts closing of fancy

```
 <script>
    $('.fancyframe').fancybox({
        'type': 'iframe',
        'height': 600,
        'width': 600,
        'onCleanup': function(){
            x = $('#fancyframe').contents().find('#url').val();
            alert(x);
        },
        'onClosed': function() {
            x = $('#fancyframe').contents().find('#url').val();
            alert(x);
        },
        'onComplete': function () {
            x = $('#fancyframe').contents().find('#url').val();
            alert(x);
        }
    });
</script>
```

call partial view

```
 @Html.ActionLink("REDIMENSIONAR", "CropImagem", "Noticia", new { Class = "fancyframe" })
```

this call opens a view.

what is missing is happening close the fancybox window and redeem the value of this hidden field. Or even take a recharged in partial view that called with the new model.

Comment: Are you sure the id fancyframe is present? Should it be #fancybox-frame ?

Comment: @ManuelvanRijn yes, it is because I can make it appear, his name is fancyframe, I caught him by the class.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

```
return Content("<script>parent.$.fancybox.close();</script>");
```

put in the return of the controller fancybox, and the value I put in a hidden field in the default template.